# How should I format the current if || (or) statement?

Tags: javascript

This is what I have right now:

```
  if (user.userId && _.include(Session.get('onlineEditors'), user.userId)) {
    return Meteor.users.findOne({_id: user.userId})
  }
```

Now I would like to add an || (or) alternative at the beginning of that if statement. Say, a variable `currentUserId`.

So the code will say: if `currentUserId` is true or `user.userId && _.include(Session.get('onlineEditors'), user.userId)` is true

How to properly format that?

Comment: (condition) or ((condition) and (condition))

Comment: I dunno why you don't know how to create a simple `||` condition and you know how to use classes and objects..

Comment: @user3355243 ha, too much stress at work today I think. I was about to delete the question but it got 3 answers before I could press the button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (currentUserId || (user.userId && _.include(Session.get('onlineEditors'), user.userId)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (currentUserId != null || (user.userId != null &&
_.include(Session.get('onlineEditors'), user.userId)))
```

Is this what you mean?